# Code does not work with sh -c, but works on sh directly

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
$ sh
sh-3.2$ if
> ps -ef | grep apple ;
> then
> echo APPLE 
> fi ;
lazer   7584  7571  0 04:36 pts/4    00:00:00 grep apple
APPLE
sh-3.2$ exit
exit
$ which sh
/bin/sh
$ /bin/sh -c if ps -ef | grep apple ; then echo APPLE fi ;
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
$
```

As above, my simple if statement works as expected when executed line by line but gives me the following error when executed using `sh -c`:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you realize that `grep` will always match itself here? What are you doing, really?

Comment: This was a small NOOP code snippet I used to show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interactive shell will be escaping the invocation via `sh -c`. In particular it's taking everyting after the semi-colon as a new statement.

Quote everything that you're feeding to `/bin/sh` e.g.

```
$ /bin/sh -c "if ps -ef | grep apple ; then echo APPLE fi ;"
```

I think you may also need to delimit further using semi-colons given that you're condensing everything onto one line, and would perhaps suggest you could use a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Comment: I get `/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file` now (after adding quotes).

Comment: It should be `/bin/sh -c 'if ps -ef | grep apple ; then echo APPLE ; fi'` - the trailing `;` is not needed but `;` after the end of `echo` and before `fi` is. The reason your multi-line version didn't have a problem is the end of the line serves as an implicit `;`. Also, generally one should use single quotes for this to avoid unintended expansions.